# function in laravel - есть ли особенности? Нужно сравнить массивы

Tags: php, laravel

Подскажите может кто сталкивался. Элементарная рнр в laravel в контроллере дает ошибку:

> ErrorException
>   array_udiff_assoc() expects parameter 3 to be a valid callback, function 'compare_quantity' not found or invalid function name

код

`

```
<?php
$a = array(1,10,0 );
$b = array( 0,5,1  );
function compare_quantity($a, $b) {
       if ($a <$b) return 1;
}

print_r (count(array_udiff_assoc($a, $b, 'compare_quantity')));
```

`
поиск не дает никакого ответа. В чем вопрос  то. Этот же код в любом php editor работает норм. версия на сервере, где laravel 7.1

Comment: предположу, что проблема с namespace

Comment: Ну не знаю - ведь laravel обращается к этому контроллеру. И  laravel использует пространство имен по умолчанию для контроллера

Comment: напишите 'namespace/compare_quantity' и расскажите, что получилось

Comment: array_udiff_assoc() expects parameter 3 to be a valid callback, function 'namespace/compare_quantity' not found or invalid function name

Comment: дак ваш namespace -  в котором функция. я не знвю, как laravel раздаеет пространство имен, что у контроллера

Comment: у контроллера namespace App\Http\Controllers;. Controllers/compare_quantity - ошибка. Ну и все варианты до полного пути тоже ошибка.

Comment: Lhttps://www.php.net/manual/ru/language.types.callable.php#119166

Comment: Спасибо! . Работает вариант App\Http\Controllers\compare_quantity - левый слэш и все с большой буквы. Это laravel упрощает работу!)

Comment: оформите в ответ?